# Manage translations

Tags: playframework, translation, translate

I would like to ask what tool do you use for updating/merging translation files.

For example imagine that we have 3 message files e.g. `messages.en`, `messages.it`, `messages.de`.

Is there a way to synchronise these files with the code? I mean:

1. Check .html files
2. Get all @Messages.get('  ')
3. Search if they are available in each file and if not just add them.

Or at least is there a tool to somehow synchronize the messages files ? For example when I add something to `messages.en` it will be automatically added to `messages.de`, etc.

I am not sure but i found this outdated plugin: https://github.com/huljas/play-messages and I would like to ask if something similar exists for play 2.4.

Comment: I've never had to provide a web page in different languages so far myself, but have you had a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N?

Comment: Yes I did. The problem is somehow automate the whole process of the message file creation etc.

Comment: I started with a sample app with 8 languages and currently Play lacks of a good translation tool. Currently I have developed some classes to manage translations in the database (generate translation files from db).

Comment: @adis is that a good solution? I think I found a better one. I will post it as soon as I finish it.